# What is the difference between StreamWriter.Flush() and StreamWriter.Close()?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

What is the difference in functionality between `StreamWriter.Flush()` and `StreamWriter.Close()`?

When my data wasn't being written correctly to a file, I added both `Flush()` and `Close()` to the end of my code.  However, I realized that adding *either* `Flush()` or `Close()` allowed the data to be written correctly.

I wasn't able to pick up on exactly what each of these methods does when I read the MSDN docs; I only figured out that one or the other is necessary to ensure data is written correctly. Any further explanation would be much appreciated.

---

Where `s` is a string to be written, here's what my code looks like currently:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("TextOutput.txt");
sw.Write(s);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

---

Based on feedback from the answers, I've rewritten my code in a `using` block, which implements `IDisposable` and will automatically take care of writing the stream to the file when the object is disposed:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("TextOutput.txt"))
{
    sw.Write(s);
}
```

Comment: Looks like StreamWriter is the one that implements iDisposable not the using block

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`StreamWriter.Flush()` can be called any time you need to clear the buffer, and the stream will remain open.

`StreamWriter.Close()` is for closing the stream, at which point the buffer is also flushed.

But you shouldn't really need to call either of these.  Any time I see a `.Close()` in code I take that as a code smell, because it usually means an unexpected exception could cause the resource to be left open.  What you *should* do, is create your `StreamWriter` variable in a using block, like this:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("somefilepath.txt"))
{
   // write a bunch of stuff here
} // the streamwriter WILL be closed and flushed here, even if an exception is thrown.
```

Comment: This because Stream.Dispose calls Close()

Comment: to be clear, enapsulating a `StreamWriter` object in a `using` (or `try`/`catch`) block will force the object to be closed?

Comment: @Ben - encapsulating it in a try/catch will _not_ force it to close.  Encapsulating your `.Close()` call in a `finally` block or `using` block will, and a using block is so much more convenient.

Comment: obviously this depends on the needs of the app in question, but my impression is if you had an exception writing to a file you would want to handle it in some way (notify user, etc.)...I actually can't think of any scenario where I would use `using` for file i/o...am I missing something?

Comment: @toasteroven - `using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.txt")) try { //writer.writestuff(); :) }catch(...) { }`

Comment: "using" cannot be used when you are using the stream writer object to write at different places in the code. In that case, you have to close the stream manually.

Comment: "But you shouldn't really need to call either of these"... not true with flush().  You may very well need to call flush() so you don't run out of memory.

Comment: @RayLoveless I have written out 100+ GB files with StreamWriter, and never seen it use much memory.  It's internal buffer should be very small, and shouldn't have any noticeable impact on memory.  It auto-flushes once the buffer fills up.

Comment: There are times when an explicit .Flush() is useful... but they are rare.

Comment: What scenarios is an explicit `Flush()` useful?

Comment: @Alsty Streams that stay open and active over longer periods of time, where there are separate readers and writers. In those cases, you flush when you finish writing a batch, to be sure it will be available to readers.

Comment: According to @davidfowl at MS, when using `WriteAsync()` you should, .."Always call `FlushAsync()` on StreamWriter(s) or Stream(s)"  The [guidance link](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#always-call-flushasync-on-streamwriters-or-streams-before-calling-dispose)  -  [@Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) - do you agree and if so would you consider updating your answer?  I realized you answered 11 years ago :)

Comment: @ttugates This answer pre-dates the Async() methods, and I haven't personally had the chance to explore them.

Comment: @ttugates David does qualifies his just as dogmatic statement with "Either use the asynchronous DisposeAsync method (for example via await using) or call FlushAsync before calling Dispose"

Answer (score 17):

`StreamWriter.Flush()` will flush anything in the Stream out to the file. This can be done in the middle of using the Stream and you can continue to write.

`StreamWriter.Close()` closes the Stream for writing. This includes Flushing the Stream one last time.

There's a better way to do things though. Since StreamWriter implements `IDisposable`, you can wrap the StreamWriter in a `using` block.

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
     // Work with things here
}
```

After the `using` block, `Dispose` will be called...which will Flush and Close the Stream for you.

Comment: Flush() does not write anything to the physical file, only to the underlying stream.

Answer (score 8):

I had a case where I was writing a very long string to a StreamWriter with an underlying MemoryStream. The MemoryStream was being consumed by something else before the writer and the stream were disposed.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream , Encoding.UTF8))
{
    streamWriter.Write(someRealyLongStringValue);
    DoSomethingWithTheStream(memoryStream );
}
```

With really long strings the end of the string was being truncated. This was resolved by calling flush before the stream was used. Alternatively I could have set AutoFlush to true.

Comment: Thanks, just ran into this issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

Flush: Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

Close: Closes the current StreamWriter object and the underlying stream.