# Generating a .txt File From a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a text file on the fly based on data gathered in a `DataTable`.

My current (test) dataset has 773 rows, which I want to split with a comma (,) for each column and break each row on a separate line. Here's my attempt;

```
string FileName = "TEST_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmm") + ".txt";

                StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"PATH...." + FileName);

                foreach (DataRow row in Product.Rows)
                {
                    bool firstCol = true;
                    foreach (DataColumn col in Product.Columns)
                    {
                        if (!firstCol) sw.Write(",");
                        sw.Write(row[col].ToString());
                        firstCol = false;
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
```

The output is a text file, as expected. Instantly, most of the data appears, but the text file never fully displays the 773 rows. I have tried this several times, the number of rows can vary from 720 rows to 750 rows all the way to partial completion of row 773, but it never finishes.

I haven't interfered with, or stopped the application at any time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block? - This will flush the buffer, to the underlying stream. - Else try call `sw.Flush()` after your foreach loop.

Comment: @ebb Using sw.Flush() did the trick, could you put that in an answer and maybe explain why, I'll gladly accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Clev231 for the reason why, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417978/what-is-the-difference-between-streamwriter-flush-and-streamwriter-close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

You need to flush the `Stream`, by either wrapping the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block, or call `sw.Flush()` at the end of your `foreach` loop.

---

**Long answer**

When using a `StreamWriter` of any kind (`StreamWriter`, `BinaryWriter`, `TextWriter`), writing to the underlying stream/device (in your case a file) - it will not write directly to the file, as this is expensive, compared to using a buffer.

(1) Imagine the following:

- You're looping through 10.000 records
- Each record is written to the file directly when invoking `.Write()`, before moving on with the next record.

(2) How it really works:

- You're looping through 10.000 records
- Each record is written to a buffer when invoking `.Write()`, before moving on to the next record.
- When the buffer reaches a certain size/number of elements it will flush to disc.

You can see that by using (2) you will gain a lot of IO performance compared to (1), as each new record doesn't need to be written to the file immediately.

So (1) would need to write to the file 10.000 times, while (2) only has to write a fraction of what (1) needs to (which could be 5.000 times, 2.000 times - it depends on how the buffer is implemented).

By wrapping the `Stream` in a `using` block, or calling `Flush()` on it, whenever you're done with the `Stream` will make it flush the buffer (and missing data) to the file.

Answer (score 0):

i can't say for sure what cause that, but i can see that you (and us) need more information.

let's start by knowing how many rows are in the `Product.Rows` by putting a breakpoint and see in a watch the `count` property.

after that, and if the number of rows is the same you though it was, put a counter on the loop and check that it passes through the  loop the same amount of times. finally, try to find the last line written to the file and debug that line in the loop step by step. you might get exception (not likely, but a possibility) and you might find out more on the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I should have stated I already knew the table contained 773 rows, the text file sometimes even showed up to the 773rd row. sw.Flush() solved my issue.

Comment: @Clev231 you mean to say that you just never closed the file...
you should always use the "using" statement when working with files and streams