# String too small to store standard output of process

Tags: c#, string, logging

I direct the standard output/error of a process and store it in a string which I log to a file.

I have noticed that not all of the standard output is stored in the text file so I must be hitting the size limit of the string.

Does anyone know of an alternative which would help satisfy this issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Logging
{
    class Logger
    {
        private FileStream file = null;
        private StreamWriter writer = null;

        public Logger(string _path)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(_path)) File.Create(_path).Dispose();

            file = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
            writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        }

        public void Log(string _text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_text);
            using (file)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now + "] : " +  _text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no sane size limit for strings.  (your process isn't writing 2GB of output)

Comment: It seems to me that it might be that you're just not flushing the writer.

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're swallowing all exceptions without reading them.  Don't do that.

Comment: Maybe use something like NLog instead of something that clearly isnt working

Comment: The flushing fixed the problem, found a useful link here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417978/what-is-the-difference-between-streamwriter-flush-and-streamwriter-close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string` type has a limit of 2GB.

Your handling of the file creation and disposal is causing you some difficulty.

Try this for a little cleaner logging code:

```
        const string log = @"logfile path";
        public void Log(string _text)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(_path, true))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now + "] : " +  _text);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
        using (file)
```

You just disposed your file.  You can't write to it anymore.