# Files is not been written c#

Tags: c#

Can someone point me what's wrong with this code? I am simply trying to write to a file, but nothing gets written to the file. Sorry this is a stupid question.. File gets created but nothing is written on to it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\File\Test.txt");
    writer.WriteLine("Fun Times!");
    Console.WriteLine("Finally !");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: See [What is the difference between StreamWriter.Flush() and StreamWriter.Close()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417978/what-is-the-difference-between-streamwriter-flush-and-streamwriter-close)

Comment: you should wrap your SteamWriter in a using statement, this will automatically close it after use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not closing the file.  One way to do this is to wrap your writer in a using statement:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\File\Test.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Fun Times!");
}

Console.WriteLine("Finally !");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to Close the StreamWriter `writer.Close();`

Comment: Of course you also can use `using`, this ensures that the object is always disposed correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("YourPathTpoFile","TheTextShouldBeWrittenInFile");
```

Have a look at its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too.

Also, If you have text in an array then you can write using [WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("YourPathTpoFile", stringArrayOfLines);
```