# Why no line is writen in output using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm having an issue with StreamWriter and I just can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
String line, new_line;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtFilePath.Text))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(txtResultFolder.Text.ToString() + "\\" + "NEW_trimmed_file" + ".csv", true))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            new_line = line.TrimEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(new_line);
            sw.WriteLine(new_line);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the MessageBox.Show(new_line), just to be sure I have a value for the StreamWriter to write, but in the resulted file I cannot find anything. 
As an additional information I have a text which has empty spaces for each line (a lot of spaces) and I'm making another file with same lines as the first, but with no spaces.
Any hints why the StreamWriter does not actually writes in the destination file?

Many thanks,

Comment: Does it work if you specify the path manually?

Comment: What is the size of the written file? 0 bytes or 1 or 2 bytes? If it is 1 or 2 bytes I suspect that you write an empty line.

Comment: @Dion V:It's not relevant. When I ran it in debug, I can see the value loaded for the "line" string (from first file) and I can see the file named "NEW_trimmed_file.csv" from my location as well. But no lines are actually written.

Comment: Did you pause the debugger at the last '}' ?

Comment: @Ako: that was why i put the messagebox.show, just to be sure the line which I intend to write has some data. Which has because the dialog box shows it. The file has 0 bytes

Comment: @BogdanM Alright, that was not clear in your question, but if that's the case then refer to Yuval's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but in the resulted file I cannot find anything

If you want your `StreamWriter` to immediately write it's buffer before disposal, you need to call `Flush()`:

```
string line, new_line;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtFilePath.Text))             
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(txtResultFolder.Text.ToString() +
                                          "\\" + "NEW_trimmed_file" + ".csv", true))
{
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      new_line = line.TrimEnd();
      MessageBox.Show(new_line);
      sw.WriteLine(new_line);
   }
   sw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `Flush()`.  `StreamWriter` automatically flushes on `Dispose()`.

Comment: @Yuval: Many, many thanks! It worked. Initially I've tried the sw.Flush() command just after sw.WriteLine(new_line), but with no effect, still an empty file. When used as you've written it worked perfectly. Many thanks again.

Comment: @Downvoter - I'd love to know what you find wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Yuval - It's incorrect information.  You don't need to call `Flush`.  See posts from [Joel Coehoorn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2417983/4698828) and [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065196/4698828).

Comment: You don't need to call `Flush` when you close the `StreamWriter`. This is wrong as @JonTirjan says. FWIW, I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much shorter way to read and write from and to files. Just use File.ReadAllLines() and `File.WriteAllLines()`

```
var content = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath.Text)

File.WriteAllLines(txtResultFolder.Text.ToString(), content);
```

I am a little confused about of the naming of `txtResultFolder`. Is this path a folder? What is the exact content of this TextBox?

Comment: the code is just a sample from my winform application. The txtResultFolder is the destination folder chosen by the user. The destination for the StreamWriter is dynamically made. I cannot use ReadAllLines and WriteAllLines because my original file which I need to "trim" has around 22 millions lines, therefore only StreamWrite and StreamRead do work (tryed what you said but crashes the server)