# StreamWriter stops in the middle of a WriteLine

Tags: c#, io, console-application, streamwriter

I have a small application that checks all of the logs in a directory named after domain usernames and generates a results file with each username and the relevant first and surname for that user.

The console is outputting the full list successfully but it seems that the `StreamWriter` is stopping halfway through an entry.

The number of characters it writes before stopping is consistent - to some extent. If I set the `outputstring` to include more characters between the two variables `filename` and the result from `FindNameFromUsername` then the character count with or without spaces changes so I've ruled that out.

Any ideas as to why the console outputs the line but the streamwriter doesn't?

Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

namespace Filename_Finder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please insert the full directory path. All filenames in the root of this folder will be logged to one file.");
            string outputFilename = "results.txt";
            string userPath = Console.ReadLine();
            string domain = "ou=users,dc=domain,dc=local";
            try
            {
                string outputFilepath = userPath + outputFilename;
                string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(userPath);
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outputFilepath, false))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string filepath = filepaths[i];
                        char split = '.';
                        string filename = filepath.Remove(0, userPath.Count());
                        if (filename != outputFilename)
                        {
                            int extensionBegins = filename.LastIndexOf(split);
                            filename = filename.Remove(extensionBegins);
                            string outputstring = (filename + " -- " + FindNameFromUsername(filename, domain));
                            Console.WriteLine(outputstring);
                            file.WriteLine(outputstring);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); Console.ReadLine(); }

        }

        public static string FindNameFromUsername(string username, string domainScope)
        {
            string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + domainScope;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)";
            filter += "(|(sAMAccountName=" + username + ")))";
            searcher.Filter = filter;
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
            string resultValue = string.Empty;
            DirectoryEntry obj = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            resultValue = "" + obj.Properties["givenName"].Value + " " + obj.Properties["sn"].Value;
            if (resultValue == " ") { resultValue = username; }
            entry.Close(); entry.Dispose();
            obj.Close(); obj.Dispose();
            searcher.Dispose();
            return resultValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Console.ReadLine()` will pause the execution and I'm guessing that's where you are checking the content of your file.

However, the file won't be [flushed and closed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) until the `StreamWriter` is being disposed. That happens at the end of the `using` block, i.e. after your `ReadLine()` statement.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417978/what-is-the-difference-between-streamwriter-flush-and-streamwriter-close).

Comment: Wow. That did the trick, I took away ReadLine. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful setting your [StreamWriter.AutoFlush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true` in order to get similar behavior to the corresponding `Console` method, like this:

```
using (var file = new StreamWriter(outputFilepath, false) { AutoFlush = true })
```