# Can't reach the code after a while-block

Tags: c#

I got a strange question in my code, I'm trying to transform a file from a server's response stream.

But when I use the `Stream.CopyTo()` or the method below and debug it, it never reaches the `fs.Flush()`.

[image]

I can reach the while-block and there is not an infinite loop. When `bs.Read` gets to the end, the loop ends too but just not reach the code after it.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: I guess your currentDataLength is always greater 0

Comment: instead of while use for loop

Comment: Show where you call `SaveFile`

Comment: the `offset` is the start index of `byteArr`,so i just update the `byteArr` in every `bs.Read(...)`  called

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint (click on left border of your code window, it will be shown as red dot). Than use f10 to jump inside your code. It probably is a infinit loop.

Comment: Please add the actual code into the question and not a screenshot of it. As it stands the question is eligible to be closed.

Comment: Might have something to do with your `bufSize` since you initialize `BufferedStream` with the default size of 4096... Look at the link below in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While is a loop that won't end until the condition equates to `false`. So let's say the value for `currentDataLength` changes with every cpu cycle, but is always greater than `0`( or never goes below `0`), it will keep going on.

Seeing that you change the value of `currentDataLength` once outside the `while` loop, and then again inside it. The chances are it will keep going on until `bs.Read()` RETURNS something negative.

A good idea would be to change the condition of the while loop. But that would depend entirely upon the usage of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you even need to call `fs.Flush()`because you are inside a `using` block - which implements `IDisposable` and should automatically take care of writing the stream to the file when the object is disposed.

I think it might have something to do with the fact that you use a large buffer size than the default for `BufferedStream` which is `4096`  bytes (you initialize `BufferedStream` with the default value). So `Read` will always end up in the case where it has read less bytes than requested. In this case read might deadlock, if you are reading from a port/pipe. Look at what's happening inside [the source code for `Read` here.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/bufferedstream.cs,59e157f1c40abad9)

Comment: This is a comment about the code not an answer to the question as asked. Also I'm pretty sure `Flush` needs to be called...

Comment: Don't think so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417978/what-is-the-difference-between-streamwriter-flush-and-streamwriter-close

Comment: I've had cases where I have needed to explicitly call `Flush`, either way you are not answering the question as asked. The OP wants to know why `Flush` is not called, not whether or not they should call it.

Comment: I've removed my downvote after your edit, it seems like a reasonable assertion. If you think the source code is relevant it might be worth adding, at least some of it, into your answer directly; license permitting of course.

Comment: Thanks, the source code has clearly commented that case.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop never returns because the param `stream` is waiting for the new response from my server. So the `Read(...)` method can never get to the end because it's waiting for the response close.

So when it gets to the end (current) of the stream, the main thread will suspend for new response and seems like the a infinite loop.

I changed my code of server and then the trouble is resolved:

```
public static void SendFile(HttpListenerResponse oResp, string filePath, long startPoint)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        fs.Seek(startPoint, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.CopyTo(oResp.OutputStream);
        //Added: close the response
        oResp.Close();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I found the `fs.Flush` from code in question description still can't reach, I guess it may not effective in `using` block.